# Avoiding schema lock cannot be acquired because of existing lock on File Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, arccatalog, schema-locks

I am having a problem with a Schema Lock in ArcMap for Desktop Advanced 10.2. The license that I have is Concurrent use for two computers. On Computer 1, I created an MXD Map File and a File Geodatabase for my map in the ArcCatalog Window. I have everything saved on the a shared folder in the E Drive over the Network.

1. I close ArcMap on this computer then open up ArcMap on Computer 2.
2. I open the MXD Map File and then open the ArcCatalog Window to add more Feature Classes to my created File Geodatabase.
3. When I try to expand the File Geodatabase on Computer 2 an error comes up stating "A schema lock cannot be acquired because of an existing lock." and the GeoDatabase will not expand for editing feature classes.

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: in order to add feature classes you have to have a schema lock. Which basically means nothing else can have any lock. you can't have the mxd open with links to the gdb and add feature classes at the same time.

Comment: If you need the MXD open, I would use the ArcCatalog *window* within ArcMap rather than the ArcCatalog program itself.

Comment: Try to compact Filegeodatabase, that might clean orphan locks

Comment: I wonder if this is an old ArcGIS bug? On computer 1, can you still see ArcMap.exe running in the task manager even after you close it?

Comment: Yes, ArcMap.exe is still running in the task manager after I close it.

Comment: If you can still see the process running then that is why it hasn't released the schema lock.  Generally, if you have layers added to an ArcMap session from a File GDB, that you are editing, you can also do other operations on that same geodatabase through that instance of ArcMap.  Problems arise when you start to have multiple instances of ArcMap open at the same time, or as in this case, when you close one but it doesn't actually close all the way and release the lock.

Comment: Accessing FGDBs over a network can also introduce issues.

Comment: I agree with @nmpeterson - the use case for ArcCatalog since the release of 10.0 has been *very* limited - with the Catalog window available just stay in ArcMap, and you should see far fewer, if any, schema lock issues.

Comment: It ended up being the file path that each of the computers are using to open the database. Once I set the same path for each computer they both were able to connect to the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When the ArcMap window dissapears that's not the end, ArcMap.exe is still running - doing some housekeeping: writing back to the Normal, updating symbol libraries and so on. If anything interrupts these processes ArcMap will still be present (and locking) and the process may hang... therein lies your problem.

In a normal situation the end of the ArcMap.exe process is seconds after the window closes and everything is fine. The challenge here is to find out why it is that your ArcMap didn't exit as normal. Check your Normal and style can be accessed and ArcMap isn't arguing with your virus checker (doesn't happen so often these days, virus checkers are getting better). Trimming your paths seems to help also, get rid of any connected folders, especially network folders, that you don't absolutely need.

But of course before you try any of this use the standard I.T. Helpdesk first response: Restart both computers.